# How to run some code at once when a image loaded?

Tags: javascript, image

I want to get a image's width when a page loaded. Because the image's width is used to judge some conditions, the logic like this:

```
var width = $('img').width();
var height = $('img').height();
if(width > height){
  //do fn1
}else{
  //do fn2
}
```

[Here is a link](http://jsbin.com/kunezi/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output) to simulate my problem. I knew if use function `setTimeout` delay to 
 get image width is available but it's not precise.

Comment: `$('img').load( fnYourHandler );`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/midecuvufu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is the example given in the jQuery documentation**:

... a page with a simple image:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book">
```

The event handler can be bound to the image:

```
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

As soon as the image has been loaded, the handler is called.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

**Here's more on the topic that will help you out:**

[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a concise answer!

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are awesome, you could create the image element, add a source, and do something when it's loaded. No jQuery needed.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    alert('image loaded');
};
image.src = 'image/image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object.onload=function(){
var width = $('img').width();
height = $('img').height();
};
```

You can try this onload function.

Answer (score 0):

You should check image width and height after image is loaded.
With JQuery you can check page load like this:

```
    $('img').load(function() {
          var width =  $('img').width();
          var height = $('img').height();

          if(width > height){
            console.log(1);
          }else{
            console.log(2);
          }
    });
```

[JS BinExample Here](http://jsbin.com/sisoxuwoki/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Even if wrap code width **$(function {})**, there is possible get zero with a image.

Comment: I updated answer, you should listen also image load.